# Updating a json field attribute

Tags: json, jsonb

This statement works fine when I hardcode the "1" in the path and "nurse" as the new value:

```
person := JSONB_SET(person, '{1, title}', '"nurse"');
```

However, I would like to be able to use the same statements with variables as:

```
xindex := '1';
xtitle := '"nurse"';

person := JSONB_SET(person, '{xindex, title}', xtitle);
```

Any Ideas?  Thank you